# Overriding a parent method

Tags: java

I have a class A
private method 1

class B extends A
private method 1 (Same name)

When I instantiate B and method 1 gets called from class A.  I made them both protected and that solved it.  Is there a way to keep both private and still get class B's method 1 to be called?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but private means private--not accessible outside the class. (Ignoring reflection.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Private is designed for that class and that class alone.

Protected is designed for any subclesses to know about, use and override if required.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) explanation of the visibility modifiers from the java tutorials, it'll be clear after that

Answer (score 0):

private methods are only accessible from that specific class so you can't override them. You can have method with same name and arguments in a subclass and there will be no errors, but it will not override it.